# C# REGEX: negative pattern replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I managed to find a nice pattern to match specific data but I am looking for the inverse pattern to be used in a Regex.Replace method to clean up useless data.

The original string:

```
<h3>Non-Human Toxicity Values:</h3>
<br />LD50 Rat oral 100 mg/kg /SRP: percent solution not specified/<br /><br />LD50 Rat (albino) oral 2020 mg/kg /From table/ /SRP: percent solution not specified/<br /><br />LD50 Rat oral 800 mg/kg /from table/<br /><br />LD50 Rat sc 420 mg/kg<br /><br />LC50 Rat inhalation 0.82 mg/L (1/2 hour)<br /><br />LC50 Rat inhalation 0.48 mg/L/4 hr<br /><br />LD50 Rat iv 87 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/<br /><br />LD50 Mouse oral 42 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/<br /><br />LD50 Mouse sc 300 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/<br /><br />LC50 Mouse inhalation 400 mg/cu m/2 hr /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/<br /><br />LC50 Mouse inhalation 0.414 mg/L/4 hr<br /><br />LD50 Mouse ip 16 mg/kg /From table/<br /><br />LD50 Guinea pig oral 260 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/<br /><br />LD50 Rabbit percutaneous 270 mg/kg /<font color="red"><strong>Formalin</strong></font>/<br /><br />LD50 Rabbit sc 240 mg/kg /From table/<br /><br />LD50 Dog sc 550 mg/kg /From table/<br /><br />
```

What I need is only the Rat and Rabbit values.

I use `((LD|LC)50 (Rat)|(Rabbit)).*?(/kg|/L/l)` to match those values but I would like a method so that anything that is not that specific pattern gets replaced.

I looked around in other threads however the solutions are exclusionary to specific character types (digits, non-digits, non-words, etc). Here I am looking for a pattern.

Comment: Gets replaced with what? It will help if you can add an example of how you want the output to look like.

Comment: To get it replaced with nothing, e.g: "".

Answer (score 1):

When you run the Regex Match - you can take the Match Groups and combine them the way you want?
**Ex:**

```
string input = @"<h3>Non-Human Toxicity Values:</h3>
<br />LD50 Rat oral 100 mg/kg /SRP: percent solution not specified/
<br /><br />LD50 Rat (albino) oral 2020 mg/kg /From table/ /SRP: percent solution not specified/
<br /><br />LD50 Rat oral 800 mg/kg /from table/
<br /><br />LD50 Rat sc 420 mg/kg
<br /><br />LC50 Rat inhalation 0.82 mg/L (1/2 hour)
<br /><br />LC50 Rat inhalation 0.48 mg/L/4 hr
<br /><br />LD50 Rat iv 87 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/
<br /><br />LD50 Mouse oral 42 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/
<br /><br />LD50 Mouse sc 300 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/
<br /><br />LC50 Mouse inhalation 400 mg/cu m/2 hr /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/
<br /><br />LC50 Mouse inhalation 0.414 mg/L/4 hr
<br /><br />LD50 Mouse ip 16 mg/kg /From table/
<br /><br />LD50 Guinea pig oral 260 mg/kg /Source contains no data on purity of the compound/
<br /><br />LD50 Rabbit percutaneous 270 mg/kg /<font color=""red""><strong>Formalin</strong></font>/
< br />< br /> LD50 Rabbit sc 240 mg / kg / From table /
      < br />< br /> LD50 Dog sc 550 mg / kg / From table /
            < br />< br /> ";

            Regex ratRabbitRegex = new Regex(@"(?<Pattern>(LD|LC)\d\d (Rat|Rabbit) (\w|\s|/)+)");

            var matches = ratRabbitRegex.Matches(input);

            var result = new List<string>();

            for (int id = 0; id < matches.Count; id++)
            {
                result.Add(matches[id].Groups["Pattern"].Value);
            }
```

Now you can format the strings in the results collection per your need.